# With TypeScript: unable to refer to 'this' (class) from inside a function

Tags: this, typescript

I'm learning `TypeScript` and have the following class:

```
class DetailDriver {

    public get driver() {
        return super.getEntity();
    }

    public activate(): breeze.Promise {
        var id = this.driver.id(); // this refers to (class) DetailDriver

        return promise
            .then(getCertificate)
            .fail(somethingWrong);

        function getCertificate() {
            var id = this.driver.id(); // this refers to any
            return ...
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see on the above code, the first call to `this` refers to my class `DetailDriver`. That's good. The second call to `this` (inside `getCertificate`) refers to `any`. That's not what I need. I need to refer to my class `DetailDriver`.

How to proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: This explains `this` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well,

According to section 4.9.2 of the TypeScript Language Specification you should use fat arrow syntax to preserve the scoping for this.

```
return promise
        .then(() => return.this.id;)
        .fail(somethingWrong);
```

Then the this keyword is properly determined to be a Driver.

Comment: What if I need to keep my `getCertificate` call (maybe I have other code inside it, not only the returned id). I saw you removed it completely. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can do it like this `() => { ...here just a func body that refers this and does whatever processing it needs ...}`

Comment: or you can name it too like that: `getCertificate = () => {
            var id = this.driver.id(); // this refers to driver
            return ...
   }`

Answer (score 1):

For reference, you could also just do:

```
class SomeClass {

    public someMethod() {
        // Do something
    }
    public anotherMethod() {
        var that = this; // Reference the class instance

        function someFunction () {
            that.someMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor to something like this:

```
class DetailDriver {

    public get driver() {
        return super.getEntity();
    }

    public activate(): breeze.Promise {
        var id = this.driver.id(); // this refers to (class) DetailDriver

        return promise
            .then(this.getCertificate.bind(this)) // <- important part
            .fail(somethingWrong);
    }

    // new method function here
    private getCertificate() {
        var id = this.driver.id(); // this refers to any
        return ...
    }
}
```

Using the `function` keyword anywhere in your class will make any reference to `this` keyword refer to that function rather than the outer class. Generally, you want to avoid defining functions inside of classes, unless you use the "fat arrow" syntax. That would look like this:

```
class DetailDriver {

    public get driver() {
        return super.getEntity();
    }

    public activate(): breeze.Promise {
        var id = this.driver.id(); // this refers to (class) DetailDriver

        return promise
            .then(() => { // <- important part
                var id = this.driver.id(); // this refers to any
                return ...
            })
            .fail(somethingWrong);
    }
}
```